# Create performance counters on remote server with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, performancecounter

Question says it all.  Can I use PowerShell to create a performance counter category and performance counters on a remote Windows server.  The server in question happens to be 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any built-in cmdlets to do that. However, since you have the entire .NET Framework at your disposal, you can use [`PerformanceCounterCategory.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountercategory.create%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to create counter categories. To create them on a remote machine, you would have to enable powershell remoting. An example, which creates a single instance category of type `NumberOfItems32`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remotemachine -ScriptBlock { [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::Create("category name", "category help", "SingleInstance", "counter name", "counter help") }
```

There are other overloads that take additional data (such as the counter type) and let you create multiple counters in the category.

Answer (score 0):

yes, use the Get-Counter command:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849685.aspx

Comment: I do not want to get counter data.  I want to create custom counters and the counter category.